# Solr Geospatial Search return wrong distances

Tags: java, solr, geolocation, geospatial, distance

I'm using the Solr 3.6.1 Webapp with the SOLR-2155 Patch for geohash field support.
I set everything up like described here: https://github.com/dsmiley/SOLR-2155

Now and then the search returns a totally false distance for every hit. Refreshing the result won't help. If I change the offset of the search (e.g. listing the 2nd page) it's all fine again. Even going back to the first page now shows up the right distance.

It's not the webapp because the json stream I get directly from Solr contains the same distances as result score. In my case it's always 20015,12km.

Here is my Query:

```
fq={!geofilt}
&fl=internalid,score
&start=0
&rows=10
&sort=geodist()+asc
&sfield=location
&pt=53.6,10.11
&d=50
&q={!func}geodist()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote SOLR-2155.  I'm not particularly happy with the distance sorting code therein; there seems to be something I overlooked.  It shouldn't be some sort of math issue, it's some sort of Lucene internals issue, I think.  If you have just one point per document, then use solr.LatLonType.  If you have multiple then.... :-( I don't know what the problem is.  In Solr 4, the replacement code for this called SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType and it uses different code but it is similar, so I'm not sure if the problem will go away or not.  But even in that case, again, I'm not at all happy with the implementation.  I know how I want to do it right, but it's not on the top of my TODO list right now.

BTW, you are basically reporting a bug, and the proper place to report a bug would be the issue tracker of the project in question -- in this case, that's GitHub SOLR-2155.  StackOverflow doesn't make sense for that.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the fast response! Didn't know it's a bug but had the fear it might be. Will try to pre-process my data to use the default Solr LatLonType. Want me to post the behaviour over on GitHub too?

Comment: Yes, that's the proper location for it and others can see the issue and track its progress.  -- or lack thereof, which is more likely